# Make a rectangle blink in PyQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

The purpose of this code is to have a square that appears in a canvas for some time and is then erased. I understand that all painting events must be handled by the overloaded function paintEvent.

However, first, the squares are not being drawn and I believe, that the times at which the squares are supposed to be drawn and erased are not being respected either. My guess is this happens due to the frequency at which the event appears.

I already tried to call QPaintEvent under the functions drawApple and eraseApple. What am I missing?

```
import sys, random
import numpy as np
import math
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPaintEvent

class Game(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.setPalette(palette)
        self.tboard = Board(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tboard)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Game')
        self.show()
    def center(self):
        screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move((screen.width()-size.width())/2, (screen.height()-size.height())/2)


class Board(QtGui.QFrame):
    BoardWidth = 400
    BoardHeight = 400
    SquareWidth = 15
    SquareHeight = 15
    Speed = 10000

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Board, self).__init__(parent)
        #self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.timer_draw = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer_draw.timeout.connect(self.drawApple)
        self.timer_draw.start(self.Speed)
        self.timer_draw.setInterval(self.Speed)
        self.timer_erase = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer_erase.timeout.connect(self.eraseApple)
        self.timer_erase.start(self.Speed + self.Speed/2)
        self.timer_erase.setInterval(self.Speed)
        self.apple_color = QtCore.Qt.red
        self.bkg_color = QtCore.Qt.white
        self.draw_apple = False
        self.x_apple = 0
        self.y_apple = 0
        self.rect = QRect(self.x_apple, self.y_apple, self.SquareWidth, self.SquareHeight)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        print "Paint Event?"
        if self.draw_apple == True:
            print "Draw"
            self.apple_color = QtCore.Qt.red
        else:
            print "Do not draw"
            self.apple_color = self.bkg_color
        painter.setPen(self.apple_color)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect)

    def drawApple(self):
        print "Enters drawApple"
        self.x_apple = np.random.randint(0, math.floor(self.BoardWidth/self.SquareWidth)) * self.SquareWidth
        self.y_apple = np.random.randint(0, math.floor(self.BoardHeight/self.SquareHeight)) * self.SquareHeight
        self.draw_apple == True


    def eraseApple(self):
        print "Enters eraseApple"
        self.draw_apple == True

def main():

   app = QtGui.QApplication([])
   game = Game()    
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Would recommend you adding a python tag alongside with python2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the `update()` function as it calls `paintEvent()`. Also I recommend using a single timer for that task. You only have to deny the variable draw_apple to change state.

```
import sys, random
import numpy as np
import math
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer, QRect
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPaintEvent

class Game(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.setPalette(palette)
        self.tboard = Board(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tboard)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Game')
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move((screen.width()-size.width())/2, (screen.height()-size.height())/2)


class Board(QtGui.QFrame):
    BoardWidth = 400
    BoardHeight = 400
    SquareWidth = 15
    SquareHeight = 15
    Speed = 10000

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Board, self).__init__(parent)
        #self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.timer_draw = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer_draw.timeout.connect(self.drawApple)
        self.timer_draw.start(self.Speed)

        self.apple_color = QtCore.Qt.red
        self.draw_apple = False
        self.x_apple = 0
        self.y_apple = 0
        self.drawApple()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        print "Paint Event?"
        if self.draw_apple == True:
            print "Draw"
            self.apple_color = QtCore.Qt.red
        else:
            print "Do not draw"
            self.apple_color = QtCore.Qt.white
        painter.setPen(self.apple_color)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect)

    def drawApple(self):
        self.draw_apple = not self.draw_apple

        self.x_apple = np.random.randint(0, math.floor(self.BoardWidth/self.SquareWidth)) * self.SquareWidth
        self.y_apple = np.random.randint(0, math.floor(self.BoardHeight/self.SquareHeight)) * self.SquareHeight

        self.rect = QRect(self.x_apple, self.y_apple, self.SquareWidth, self.SquareHeight)
        self.update()

def main():

   app = QtGui.QApplication([])
   game = Game()    
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```