# Pyside6 Animated Rectangle trouble

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

I'm trying to make fading looped rectangle area. I used base code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493633/make-a-rectangle-blink-in-pyqt)
Just decided expand it.
Its just blinking rectangle, but I need smooth fade-in and fade-out effects. So I decided to make method which will calulate new opacity percent and set it to painter. But it doesnt work in cycle.

This is my class now

```
class HighlightRect(QFrame):
board_width = 400  # width of frame
board_height = 400  #height of frame

def __init__(self, parent, x, y, width=50, height=50, blink_speed=1000):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.blink_speed = blink_speed
    self.opacity_timer = self.blink_speed
    self.board_height = self.parent().height()
    self.board_width = self.parent().width()
    self.square_height = height
    self.square_width = width
    self.highlight_x = x
    self.highlight_y = y


    #self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
    self.timer_draw = QtCore.QTimer(self)
    self.timer_draw.timeout.connect(self.draw)
    self.timer_draw.start(self.blink_speed)

    self.color = QtCore.Qt.red
    self.is_draw = False
    self.x_apple = 0
    self.y_apple = 0
    self.draw()

def blink(self, painter):
    self.color = QtCore.Qt.red
    while self.opacity_timer >= 0:
        self.opacity_timer -= 1 / 10  # просто подбор
        percents = round(int(self.opacity_timer / self.blink_speed * 100)/100, 1)
        print(percents)
        painter.setOpacity(percents)



def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

    print ("Paint Event?")
    if self.is_draw == True:
        print ("Draw")
        #self.color = QtCore.Qt.red
        self.blink_thread = threading.Thread(name='background', target=lambda: self.blink(painter))
        self.blink_thread.start()
    else:

        self.opacity_timer = self.blink_speed
        print ("Do not draw")
        self.color = QtCore.Qt.transparent
        threading.SystemExit = SystemExit
    painter.setPen(self.color)
    painter.drawRect(self.rect)

def draw(self):
    self.is_draw = not self.is_draw
    self.rect = QRect(self.highlight_x, self.highlight_y, self.square_width, self.square_height)
    self.update()
```

Changind of  opacity inside blink function but outside while loop works as well, but its static. No changes. Changing opacity in loop isn't work.
Whats wrong?
Maybe somewhere here is another more correct way to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a QProperty that handles opacity and then use QPropertyAnimation to make the change smooth.

```py
import random
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Property, Signal, QPropertyAnimation, QRect, Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QFrame, QApplication


class Board(QFrame):
    rect_opacity_changed = Signal(name="rectOpacityChanged")

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Board, self).__init__(parent)

        self._rect_opacity = 1.0
        self._rect = QRect(0, 0, 50, 50)

        self._opacity_animation = QPropertyAnimation(
            targetObject=self, propertyName=b"rect_opacity", duration=3000
        )
        for p, v in ((0.0, 0.0), (0.3, 1.0), (0.7, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)):
            self._opacity_animation.setKeyValueAt(p, v)

        self._opacity_animation.finished.connect(self.change)

        self.change()

    @Property(float, notify=rect_opacity_changed)
    def rect_opacity(self):
        return self._rect_opacity

    @rect_opacity.setter
    def rect_opacity(self, opacity):
        self._rect_opacity = opacity
        self.rect_opacity_changed.emit()
        self.update()

    def change(self):
        x = random.randint(0, self.width() - self._rect.width())
        y = random.randint(0, self.height() - self._rect.height())
        self._rect.moveTo(x, y)
        self._opacity_animation.start()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setOpacity(self.rect_opacity)
        painter.setPen(Qt.red)
        painter.drawRect(self._rect)


def main():

    app = QApplication([])
    board = Board()
    board.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi! I have one more question) 
Why i see this Board-rectangle over Qlabel if I create it from __init__ of QFrame with this QLabel, and don't see if I try dynamically create Board instances in function instead of __init__ of QFrame. 
So just cut/paste creating of Board instance from init to function ruins everything/ How could it happen?

Comment: @ВладиславСтадник SO rules: 1) The comments are only used to discuss the problems, improvements, etc. of the post, they are not used for other problems. 2) If you have a problem then create a new post. We are a quality Q&A site so the posts (and comments) must be accurate, we are not a consulting service, tutoring, etc. We only solve the problem that the OP raises in his post. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]